# Is there a way to prefer a specific build agent in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Let's say I have 3 build agents for a particular pool. Is there a way to prefer one over the others if all of them are idle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TFS 2017 - Build agents priority and order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228263/tfs-2017-build-agents-priority-and-order)

Comment: Also https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-Agent-Priority/365620 (no it is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

The question here: why do you want to do that? if you have free agents - just build )))

but if you want some specific agent, add the user capability and use it in your build definition: [Configure agent capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#configure-agent-capabilities), [Manually entered agent demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).